# "BusyError: cannot rollback savepoint - SQL statements in progress" when using SQLite with APSW

Tags: python, sqlite, apsw

I'm working with an SQLite database using the Python apsw bindings. The code goes like this:

```
with apsw.Connection(path) as t:
    c = t.cursor()
    c.execute(...)
    ... more code ...
    if c.execute(...).next()[0]:
        raise Exception
```

I expect the `with` statement to put a savepoint and the `raise` statement to rollback to that savepoint (or, if there's nothing to raise, commit the transaction). It commits just fine, but when there's something to `raise` it refuses to rollback with:

```
BusyError: BusyError: cannot rollback savepoint - SQL statements in progress
```

I'm not sure where to look first. As far as I understand the error means there's another connection that blocks the access, but this doesn't look so from the code, and, if this was so, wouldn't it fail on commits as well?

SQLite 3.7.7.1, matching `apsw`, Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found it:

```
if c.execute(...).next()[0]:
    raise Exception
```

The problem is that at the moment I get the next row with `next()`, the underlying cursor stays active, ready to return more rows. It has to be closed explicitly:

```
if c.execute(...).next()[0]:
    c.close()
    raise Exception
```

or implicitly, by reading out all data:

```
if list(c.execute(...))[0][0]:
    raise Exception
```

UPDATE. For convenience I wrote a Python class that wraps `apsw.Cursor` and provides [a context manager](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers), so I can write:

```
with Cursor(connection) as c:
    c.execute(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

This was an issue in SQLite itself.  It was fixed in March 2012, in version 3.7.11.  From the [changelog](http://sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_11):

> Pending statements no longer block ROLLBACK. Instead, the pending statement will return SQLITE_ABORT upon next access after the ROLLBACK.